# JQuery submit select field on change, ajax results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

in my rails app, I have a select field by itself in a form. When the field changes I would like it to submit the form, and remotely retrieve the results.

Here is my current code (EDIT - this part works, I'm trying to add more to it):

```
$(function() {
  $("#statusFilter").live("change", function() {
    this.submit();
  });
});
```

In a different part of the app I have the following, for a hyperlink, when clicked, returns the link remotely. So I'd like the same effect for the above form.

```
$(function() {
  $("#posts_container th a").live("click", function() {
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

here is another example of how it works with a search form

```
  $("#dash_search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#dash_search").attr("action"), $("#dash_search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
```

The content I'm trying to remotely refresh lives in the posts_container

Answer (score 4):

I personally wouldn't use a form around the select field in this instance if you are not using the form to house any other form elements.

From what you have said it looks like you are trying to achieve the following:

1. A user changes the select field.
2. The new value in the select field is then used to update the posts_container field.

If I have this correct I would code the following:

**Select Field**

```
<div>
    <select id="statusFilter">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <!-- Other options... -->
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#statusFilter").change(function() {
            // Possibly show an ajax loading image $("#ajax_loading").show();
            $("#posts_container").load("somepage.php", { value: $(this).val() }, function() {
                // Do something to say the data has loaded sucessfully
                // Possibly hide the ajax loading image $("#ajax_loading").hide();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I don't know if that helps or is on the right lines, but let me know and I will try and help further if not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("#statusFilter").live("change", function() {
    //$(this).closest("form").submit();
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    $.post( {
       url: $form.action, 
       data: $form.serialize(),
       success: function(){ //Write code here to handle on success }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I understand this will submit the closest form - but will it get the results through ajax?

Comment: No, you will have to write code to make a ajax call. This will right away submit the containing form.

Comment: That didn't really address the question in my post then

Comment: @Elliot - Why down vote, I have edited my answer please take a look before giving down vote.

Comment: I've removed the downvote, but your answer seems overly complicated.. I'm using "$.getScript(this.href);" while trying to achieve the same thing for a hyperlink (and it is successful) - shouldn't there be a similar solution for this form?

Comment: $.getScript will get the script from server but in this case you want to submit and form using ajax so you cannot use getScript. I hope you understand.

Comment: I just updated my post with another example. I've made this work in the past with a search form. Granted,  I was following a tutorial - so its not much help now.

Comment: The example which you have shown used $.get and not getScript. You can use $.get but you have to pass the form data as querystring params.